# How can I render a page and generate metadata with just one request?

Tags: next.js

I need to generate metadata and render a page with **just one request**. I want to use one request because I'm building a blog page, and multiple requests or caching cause viewCounter to count incorrectly. My current code is as follows.

Get Blog Function:

```js
export async function getTurkishPostBySlug(TrSlug) {
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/post/${TrSlug}`, { cache: "no-store" })
    if (res.status === 200) {
        return res.json()
    } else {
        return "err"
    }
}
```

page.js:

```js
export async function generateMetadata({ params, searchParams }, parent) {
    const res = await getTurkishPostBySlug(params.slug)
    if (res.blog) {
        return {
            title: res.blog.TR_title,
        }
    }
}

async function CodeDetail({params}) {
    let post = null
    
    let res = await getTurkishPostBySlug(params.slug)
    if (res.blog) {
        post = res.blog
    }

    if (post) {
        return ("RENDER HERE...")
```

I tried caching but counted wrong.

Comment: [Metadata is defined as the data providing information about one or more aspects of the data;](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata#:~:text=Metadata%20is%20defined%20as%20the%20data%20providing%20information%20about%20one%20or%20more%20aspects%20of%20the%20data%3B).   Which one or more aspects are your referring to ?

Comment: Maybe it is better to stop counting requests coming from `localhost` (or any other 'special' address)?

Comment: @Luuk I want to create <Head></Head> element

Comment: @Luuk I want use a viewCounter, this is a blog page

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to have one call for `generateMetadata` and the page component. But since you are using [`fetch()`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/fetch), on production (after you build and start the project), the two calls result in one, as you can read on the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#request-memoization):

> React extends the `fetch` API to automatically memoize requests that have the same URL and options. This means you can call a fetch function for the same data in multiple places in a React component tree while only executing it once.

[image]

So there is no performance problem if you could ignore what happens during development.

Answer (score 0):

I solved with wrote a custom cache for one request, new codes is as follows

cache service

```js
const { getTurkishPostBySlug } = require("./service")

let trMap = new Map()

const cacheForTrBlog = async(slug) => {
    let post = trMap.get(slug)
    if (post === undefined) {
        const res = await getTurkishPostBySlug(slug)
        if (res?.blog) {
            trMap.set(slug, res)
            return res
        } else {
            return "err"
        }
    } else {
        trMap.delete(slug)
        return post
    }
}

module.exports = {
    cacheForTrBlog
}
```

Page.js

```js
export async function generateMetadata({ params, searchParams }, parent) {
    const res = await cacheForTrBlog(params.slug)
    if (res?.blog) {
        return {
            title: res.blog.TR_MetaTitle,
            description: res.blog.TR_MetaDescription,
            ...
        }
    }
}

async function CodeDetail({params}) {
    let post = null
    
    let res = await cacheForTrBlog(params.slug)
    if (res) {
        post = res.blog
    }

    if (post) {
        return ("RENDER...")
```

Answer (score 0):

if u set 'no-store', that request will do n times;
but if u don't set cache,that requset will only do one times;

and if u want get newest content from api in next page rendering,
u can use revalidatePath function to revalidate the pageUrl.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a chat forum. Rather, it is an encyclopaedia-like knowledge base. As such, you should avoid using slang, mobile-phone-type slang abbreviations like "u" and use full, correct English words. Please edit your post accordingly.